# Autofac: Substitute implementation but inject old implementation?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am writing an event sourced application. I have an `IEventStore` which is implemented by an `EventStore` class. However, when debugging, I would like to implement the `IEventStore` as a `DebuggingEventStore` class.

Can I somehow in the constructor of `DebuggingEventStore` get my `EventStore` (the old implementation) injected? I've looked at decorators, but I am not sure if it's the right approach in this scenario.

## Before

`IEventStore` was implemented as `EventStore`.

## Now

`IEventStore` is implemented as `DebuggingEventStore` when debugging.

## What I want

`DebuggingEventStore` injects the old `IEventStore` (the `EventStore`) in through its constructor.

Comment: Yep, you are on the right track. You need to register it as a decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your DebuggingEventStore to take in a EventStore in its constructor that gets injected when you build the iOS container.

Effectively, DebuggingEventStore will implement IEventStore and take in EventStore as a constructor parameter.

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<EventStore>().AsSelf();
    builder.Register(cc => new DebugingEventStore(cc.Resolve<EventStore>())).As<IEventStore>();
    var container = builder.Build();

    container.Resolve<IEventStore>().DoWork();

}

public interface IEventStore
{
    void DoWork();
}

public class EventStore : IEventStore
{
    public EventStore(Foo doo, Bar bar)
   { ....} 
    void IEventStore.DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EventStore");
    }
}

public class DebuggingEventStore: IEventStore
{
    private IEventStore _internalEventStore;

    public DebuggingEventStore(IEventStore eventStore)
    {
        this._internalEventStore = eventStore;
    }
    void IEventStore.DoWork()
    {
        this._internalEventStore.DoWork();
        Console.WriteLine("DebuggingEventStore");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the question properly. I am already injecting a `DebuggingEventStore` when debugging. That's not the problem.

Comment: @KnightFox much better, but I would like `EventStore` to still be resolved by the IOC container, as it doesn't have an empty constructor. Is that still possible?

Comment: @dotnetom why is there a need for code? I made the question very brief. I can't even see how anyone can misunderstand it if they read it carefully. I updated it slightly though.

Comment: you could resolve individual parameters in the constructor of EventSource as I changed in the new edit of my solution

Comment: That opens up the problem of code maintainability. I would have to correct my code in several places every time I add a new dependency. Is there no way to make it cleaner?

Comment: How about registering EventService AsSelf?

Comment: That's pretty brilliant. Thanks! I converted my vote to an upvote and marked it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/decorator-support-in-autofac-2-4/) by Nicholas Blumhardt, the typical way to register (non-generic) decorators in Autofac is as follows:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<EventStore>()
    .Named<IEventStore>("implementor");

builder.RegisterDecorator<IEventStore>(
    (c, decoratee) => new DebuggingEventStore(decoratee),
    fromKey: "implementor");
```

But that said, I think @KnightFox's answer is cleaner when it comes to registering non-generic decorators:

```
builder.RegisterType<EventStore>().AsSelf();
builder.Register(c => new DebugingEventStore(c.Resolve<EventStore>()))
    .As<IEventStore>();
```